# Getting "Warning: mysqli_connect(): (2800/1045)" even though my username and password are correct

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When I am trying to submit values on to a mySQL database via a PHP script, I get the following error

```
Warning:Warning: mysqli_connect(): (28000/1045): Access denied for user 'appacmef_appuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
in /home/appacmefg/public_html/scripts/submitclocking.php on line 2
Failed to connect to MySQL: Access denied for user 'appacmef_appuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have checked, and all the username and password details I am using in the code match up to the phpMyAdmin details.

The code is as follows;

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","appacmef_appuser","*******","appacmef_App");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security
$employeeid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['employeeid']);
$time = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['time']);
$longitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['longitude']);
$lattitude = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['lattitude']);
$vanreg = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_GET['vanreg']);


$sql="INSERT INTO clockings (employeeid, time, longitude, lattitude, vanreg)
VALUES ('$employeeid', '$time', '$longitude', '$lattitude', '$vanreg')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I have used this exact script before on an older server (With the only difference being the username and password), and it has worked fine.
Help with this would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct?

Comment: I have checked and the credentials are correct

Comment: Hate to say it, but it looks like the username and password might be wrong. Easy fix is to copy the username from mysql and paste it in your code and to reset the password, again copy-pasting between to make 100% sure.

Comment: Make sure the user is 100% definitely allowed to access from `localhost`.

Answer (score 1):

There are few steps to check and resolve this issue:

1. Make sure that your credentials are correct.
2. Check the privileges of that user by using the query: `select * from mysql.user where user = "username";`
   Are there privileges all in `Y`? If not then update this row with `Y`.
3. Check the privileges by using the query: `select * from information_schema.USER_PRIVILEGES where GRANTEE = "'username'@'localhost'"`. 
   Are there all the privileges granted or not. If not then update it.

By using these steps you can resolve your issue.